# Exporting sheet data to JSON file

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

This is my simple Sheet divided by freezed rows to Head and Body:
[image]
And this is what the final output(json) should look like:

```
{
   "3":{
      "AB1":{
         "A2":"A3",
         "B2":"B3"
      },
      "C1":{
         "C2":"C3"
      }
   },
   "4":{
      "AB1":{
         "A2":"A4",
         "B2":"B4"
      },
      "C1":{
         "C2":"C4"
      }
   },
   ...
}
```

My code look like this:

```
function doGet() {
  var SpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Sheet = SpreadSheet.getSheets()[1];

  var FirstRow = 1;
  var FirstColumn = 1;
  var LastRow = Sheet.getLastRow();
  var LastColumn = Sheet.getLastColumn();    
  var FrozenRows = Sheet.getFrozenRows();
  var FrozenColumns = Sheet.getFrozenColumns();
  
  var HeadRange = Sheet.getRange(FirstRow, FirstColumn + FrozenColumns, FrozenRows - FirstRow + 1, LastColumn - FrozenColumns); // A1:C2
  var HeadData = HeadRange.getValues(); // [[AB1, , C1], [A2, B2, C2]]
  
  var BodyRange = Sheet.getRange(FirstRow + FrozenRows, FirstColumn + FrozenColumns, LastRow - FrozenRows, LastColumn - FrozenColumns); // A3:C6
  var BodyData = BodyRange.getValues(); // [[A3, B3, C3], [A4, B4, C4], [A5, B5, C5], [A6, B6, C6]]
```

and will end with this:

```
var OutputData = ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(InputData)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
return OutputData;
```

and now my problems :), first problem is, how get value from empty merged cell, when don't know his range, only know other side when know range and want value

```
for (var i = 0; i < HeadData[0].length; i++) {
    var Category = HeadData[0][i];
var CellValue = (RangeCell.isPartOfMerge() ? RangeCell.getMergedRanges()[0].getCell(1,1) : RangeCell).getValue();
```

Second problem is, how put code together when want start json with number of row data, then category, subcategory and last with item data:

```
  var Obj = {};
  for (var i = 1; i <= ItemsRange.getNumRows(); i++) {
    var ItemIndex = ItemsRange.getCell(i,1).getRowIndex();
    for (var j = 0; j < BodyData.length; j++) {
      for (var k = 0; k < BodyData[j].length; k++) {
        var ItemCell = BodyData[j][k];        
      }
    }
    Obj[ItemIndex] = {};
  }
```

Comment: *how get value from empty merged cell, when don't know his range, only know other side when know range and want value* Could you rephrase that? If A1:B1 is merged, A1 contains the value and B1 is empty. As you said `// [[AB1, , C1], [A2, B2, C2]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, how about the following flow?

1. Retrieve values from Spreadsheet.

   - This is from your script.
2. Recreate header rows.
3. Create the result object.

#### Modification points:

- In this modification, at first, the header data is created. The merged ranges can be retrieve by `getMergedRanges()`. I created the header data using this.

  - When your sample Spreadsheet is used, `HeadData` becomes `[[AB1, AB1, C1], [A2, B2, C2]]` from `[[AB1, , C1], [A2, B2, C2]]`.
- In your case, it has already been found that the result object is the nested object with 3 levels. I think that this can be used.

#### Modified script:

```
function doGet() {
  // 1. Retrieve values from Spreadsheet. This is from your script.
  var SpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var Sheet = SpreadSheet.getSheets()[1];
  var FirstRow = 1;
  var FirstColumn = 1;
  var LastRow = Sheet.getLastRow();
  var LastColumn = Sheet.getLastColumn();    
  var FrozenRows = Sheet.getFrozenRows();
  var FrozenColumns = Sheet.getFrozenColumns();
  
  var HeadRange = Sheet.getRange(FirstRow, FirstColumn + FrozenColumns, FrozenRows - FirstRow + 1, LastColumn - FrozenColumns); // A1:C2
  var HeadData = HeadRange.getValues(); // [[AB1, , C1], [A2, B2, C2]]
  
  var BodyRange = Sheet.getRange(FirstRow + FrozenRows, FirstColumn + FrozenColumns, LastRow - FrozenRows, LastColumn - FrozenColumns); // A3:C6
  var BodyData = BodyRange.getValues(); // [[A3, B3, C3], [A4, B4, C4], [A5, B5, C5], [A6, B6, C6]]
  
  // 2. Recreate header rows.
  Sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, Sheet.getLastColumn()).getMergedRanges().forEach(r => {
    let temp = "";
    for (let i = r.getColumn(); i <= r.getNumColumns(); i++) {
      if (HeadData[0][i - 1].toString() != "") temp = HeadData[0][i - 1];
    }
    for (let i = r.getColumn(); i <= r.getNumColumns(); i++) {
      HeadData[0][i - 1] = temp;
    }
  });
  
  // 3. Create the result object.
  const InputData = BodyData.reduce((o1, r, i) => {
    o1[i + FirstRow + FrozenRows] = r.reduce((o2, c, j) => {
      const t1 = HeadData[0][j];
      const t2 = {[HeadData[1][j]]: c};
      return Object.assign(o2, {[t1]: o2[t1] ? Object.assign(o2[t1], t2) : t2});
    }, {});
    return o1;
  }, {});
  
  var OutputData = ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(InputData)).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
  return OutputData;
}
```

#### Result:

When your sample Spreadsheet is used, the value of `InputData` is as follows.

```
{
  "3": {
    "AB1": {
      "A2": "A3",
      "B2": "B3"
    },
    "C1": {
      "C2": "C3"
    }
  },
  "4": {
    "AB1": {
      "A2": "A4",
      "B2": "B4"
    },
    "C1": {
      "C2": "C4"
    }
  },
  "5": {
    "AB1": {
      "A2": "A5",
      "B2": "B5"
    },
    "C1": {
      "C2": "C5"
    }
  },
  "6": {
    "AB1": {
      "A2": "A6",
      "B2": "B6"
    },
    "C1": {
      "C2": "C6"
    }
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- **When you modified the script of Web Apps, please redeploy the Web Apps as new version. By this, the latest script is reflected to the Web Apps. Please be careful this.**
- When your actual situation is largely different from your sample Spreadsheet in your question, this modified script might not work. So please be careful this.
- Please use this modified script with V8.

#### References:

- [getMergedRanges()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getmergedranges)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [Object.assign()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: Hi, If I can ask you again, I don't understand from this line `return Object.assign(o2, {[t1]: o2[t1] ? Object.assign(o2[t1], t2) : t2});` first part `[t1]: o2[t1]`. Why is only condition `o2[t1]` and not whole part started with `{` and ended to `?`. Thank you.

Comment: @Hydro About your additional question, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about it. About `Object.assign(o2, {[t1]: o2[t1] ? Object.assign(o2[t1], t2) : t2})`, in this case, when "o2" has the key of "t1", the object "t2" adds to the object "o2[t1]". By this, in the sample output, `"AB1": {"A2": "A3", "B2": "B3"}` is created.

Comment: Hi, sry for my english, I just don't understand why in "conditional ternary operator" (condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse) that condition what JS take is only `o2[t1]` and `[t1]:` before him is ignored. I mean everything before question mark is condition after `Object.assign(o2,` Thank you.

Comment: @Hydro Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about your additional question. For example, when you want to know `{[t1]: o2[t1] ? Object.assign(o2[t1], t2) : t2}`, in this case, it can be separated with the key and value like `[t1]` and `o2[t1] ? Object.assign(o2[t1], t2) : t2`, respectively. Does this answer for your additional question?